# How to accelerate leftouterjoin in Spark?

Tags: python, optimization, apache-spark, left-join, query-optimization

How to  accelerate leftouterjoin in spark
I run a job in Spark. 
 The leftouterjoin become the bottleneck for the whole job.
So it is necessary to optimize the leftouterjoin in spark. 
It is a leftouterjoin between 2 millions record of data sets.
It is taking 8 minutes to compute the leftouterjoin
13

> leftOuterJoin at :26
>       2015/07/28 04:38:16     8.3 min 
>   7/7
>       152.7 MB        50.5 MB 278.5 MB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you used `partitionBy` and `persist` in your RDD ?

To improve performance, I suggest you should use partionby and persist on the left(in left outer join) RDD.

sample Code:

```
val leftRDD = sc.textFile(//..).partitionBy(numPartitions).persist()
```

`numPartitions` : depends on your cluster hardware. Number of cores (if you have 4 core machine then opt for `numPartitions` = 8)